# Table Name Display

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a function to show the table name at sql server? 
I want to check if the user is found at a specific table, the table's name should be returned, can I do it?

```
 IF EXISTS(
 SELECT        Std_ID
 FROM            Student
 WHERE Std_ID = @UserId)
```

I want it here to return Student.

Comment: No, but the object name in that example cannot be dynamic just select the literal `Student` ?

Comment: tables can be found in sys.tables, you can select them. If oyu only want back the table in that case Chris answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know you're going to check the Student table, just return the value 'Student'

```
if(exists(select * from Student where Std_ID = @UserId))
begin
  select 'Student' as TableName
  return;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query which check the table is already in sys.object and if it is there then it returns the name of table.

```
select name from sys.objects where type = 'U' and name = 'Student'
```